# Javacpp: liblept.4.dylib library not loaded

Tags: java, c++, linux, tesseract, javacpp

On my 64 bit Mac OSX Trying to use a native C++ library from a java project just as described in this link:

https://github.com/bytedeco/javacpp-presets/tree/master/tesseract

But I get this error when I run the example, library liblept.4.dylib is not loaded, and I have no idea what to do.

```
java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: no jnilept in java.library.path
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadLibrary(ClassLoader.java:1865)

Caused by:java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError:/private/var/folders/h8/wpw5p9196v1dz0hcy_s66_5w0000gn/T/javacpp21146551279247/libjnilept.dylib: dlopen(/private/var/folders/h8/wpw5p9196v1dz0hcy_s66_5w0000gn/T/javacpp21146551279247/libjnilept.dylib, 1): Library not loaded: /Users/saudet/projects/bytedeco/javacpp-presets/leptonica/cppbuild/macosx-x86_64/lib/liblept.4.dylib
Referenced from: /private/var/folders/h8/wpw5p9196v1dz0hcy_s66_5w0000gn/T/javacpp21146551279247/libjnilept.dylib
```

UPDATE: I tried to install tesseract and leptonica libraries via mac ports, this error has disappered but a new error came "java failed to write core dump, problematic frame leptonica..etc"

So I removed all installed libraries again returned back to same error

Answer (score 4, accepted):

That's an issue that's been fixed:
https://github.com/bytedeco/javacpp-presets/issues/46
Not released yet though, but it's easy enough to compile from source. First, get the latest source code for both JavaCPP and the JavaCPP Presets from GitHub, then run `mvn install` under `javacpp`, and then, under `javacpp-presets`, execute `bash cppbuild.sh install leptonica tesseract` before calling `mvn install -pl .,leptonica,tesseract`.

Comment: Thanks! We also e-mailed this morning, will try soon

Comment: I tried to follow the instruction here, but got error: `configure: error: installation or configuration problem: assembler cannot create object files.` when run `bash cppbuild.sh install leptonica tesseract`. I checked out 1.0 tag, same error.

Comment: @jiwhiz Maybe it wants `yasm`. That's something I always have installed because it's required here and there.

Comment: Yes, it needs yasm. After install yasm from this instruction: http://superuser.com/questions/844683/how-to-install-yasm-1-2-0-and-compile-ffmpeg-library-on-mac, I can build tesseract. thanks.

Comment: @SamuelAudet could you please help me too. I am having a bit similar issue but i am using javacpp 1.2 and I read this issue with javacpp is resolved in javacpp-1.1 .. link to my question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39435993/getting-unsatisfiedlinkerror-no-jnilept-in-java-library-path-when-i-create-tess