# in thread "main" java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: no jnilept in java.library.path

Tags: java

I have created a project for OCR

```
TessBaseAPI instance =  new TessBaseAPI();
instance.Init("C:\\TIAA Info\\tessdata","eng");
PIX image = lept.pixRead("C:\\TIAA Info\\tessdata\\test.png");
instance.SetImage(image);
BytePointer bytePointer = instance.GetUTF8Text();
String output = bytePointer.getString();
System.out.println(output);
```

After executing , I am getting following error

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: no jnilept in java.library.path
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadLibrary(ClassLoader.java:1864)
    at java.lang.Runtime.loadLibrary0(Runtime.java:870)
    at java.lang.System.loadLibrary(System.java:1122)
    at org.bytedeco.javacpp.Loader.loadLibrary(Loader.java:1302)
    at org.bytedeco.javacpp.Loader.load(Loader.java:1043)
    at org.bytedeco.javacpp.Loader.load(Loader.java:935)
    at org.bytedeco.javacpp.lept.<clinit>(lept.java:10)
    at java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)
    at java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:348)
    at org.bytedeco.javacpp.Loader.load(Loader.java:994)
    at org.bytedeco.javacpp.Loader.load(Loader.java:935)
    at org.bytedeco.javacpp.tesseract$TessBaseAPI.<clinit>(tesseract.java:3682)
    at imageTestProj.ReadDataFromImage.main(ReadDataFromImage.java:19)
Caused by: java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: no liblept in java.library.path
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadLibrary(ClassLoader.java:1864)
    at java.lang.Runtime.loadLibrary0(Runtime.java:870)
    at java.lang.System.loadLibrary(System.java:1122)
    at org.bytedeco.javacpp.Loader.loadLibrary(Loader.java:1302)
    at org.bytedeco.javacpp.Loader.load(Loader.java:1021)
    ... 8 more
```

I have used following jars

- /lib/javacpp-1.4.4.jar
- /lib/leptonica-1.77.0-1.4.4.jar
- /lib/tesseract-4.0.0-1.4.4.jar

Comment: where and how is `lept` defined?

Comment: Take a look at this other question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39435993/getting-unsatisfiedlinkerror-no-jnilept-in-java-library-path-when-i-create-tess

Comment: I have done the steps mentioned in the links but it was not working for me

Comment: @Lino lept is class provided by javacpp which has a static native method pixRead.

Comment: You'll also need to include JAR files with "linux", "macosx", and "windows" in their names.

Answer (score 0):

I hit this same error, turned out to be simply that I had defaulted to a 32 bit project, and the example is 64 bit.  Changed that and it worked perfectly.